# Cosmos DB - Some records failing to insert

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

We have a recursive function we are using to bulk insert records into Cosmos.
While running a long migration to insert many records it appears that some records failed to insert but we have been unable to see why from the logging we have.
My assumption is a certain type of status code is not being retried when it should be or something is failing silently.

Can anyone advise what might be causing records to fail without being logged/being retried?

`AllowBulkExecution = true` is set when creating the container that is passed in to the code below.

```
public async Task<bool> TryBulkInsertAsync<T>(List<T> audits, int retryAttempts, TimeSpan retryDelay, int currentAttempt = 0, Container container = null) where T : BaseCosmosModel
    {
        if (currentAttempt > retryAttempts)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Failed number of max retries ${retryAttempts}");
            return false;
        }

        if (container == null)
        {
            container = _cosmosContainerFactory.BuildCosmosContainer<T>();
        }
        
        var attemptAudits = audits.Select(a => new CosmosInsertAttempt<T>
        {
            Audit = a,
            RunningTask = container.CreateItemAsync(a)
        }).ToList();

        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(attemptAudits.Select(a => a.RunningTask));

            var failedAudits = attemptAudits.Where(a =>
                a.RunningTask.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests ||
                a.RunningTask.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed ||
                a.RunningTask.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout ||
                a.RunningTask.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable
            ).Select(a => a.Audit).ToList();

            var nonRetryableAudits = attemptAudits.Where(a =>
                !failedAudits.Contains(a.Audit) && (a.RunningTask.Result.StatusCode < (HttpStatusCode) 200 ||
                a.RunningTask.Result.StatusCode > (HttpStatusCode) 299));

            foreach (var audit in nonRetryableAudits)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Audit failed to bulk insert with non-retryable status code {cosmosAuditInsert}", audit.Audit);
            }

            if (failedAudits.Count > 0)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Retrying bulk insert from incorrect status code but no error, count: {retrySize}", failedAudits.Count);
                return await TryBulkInsertAsync(failedAudits, retryAttempts, retryDelay, currentAttempt + 1, container);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            await Task.Delay(retryDelay);
            var failedAuditsWithException = attemptAudits
                .Where(a => a.RunningTask.Exception != null)
                .Select(a => a.Audit).ToList();

            var failedAuditsWithBadStatusCode = attemptAudits.Where(a =>
            (
                a.RunningTask.Exception == null && a.RunningTask.Result != null &&
                (a.RunningTask.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests ||
                 a.RunningTask.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed ||
                 a.RunningTask.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout ||
                 a.RunningTask.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable)
            )).Select(a => a.Audit).ToList();

            if (failedAuditsWithBadStatusCode.Any())
            {
                _logger.LogError("Retrying bulk insert from incorrect status code but no error (some have exceptions), count: {retrySize}", failedAuditsWithBadStatusCode.Count);
            }

            var failedAudits = failedAuditsWithException.Concat(failedAuditsWithBadStatusCode).ToList();

            var nonRetryableAudits = attemptAudits.Where(a =>
                !failedAudits.Contains(a.Audit) && a.RunningTask.Exception == null && (a.RunningTask.Result.StatusCode < (HttpStatusCode)200 ||
                                                    a.RunningTask.Result.StatusCode > (HttpStatusCode)299));

            foreach (var audit in nonRetryableAudits)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Audit failed to bulk insert with non-retryable status code {cosmosAuditInsert}", audit.Audit);
            }

            if (failedAudits.Count > 0)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Retrying bulk insert {failedAuditCount}", failedAudits.Count);
                return await TryBulkInsertAsync(failedAudits, retryAttempts, retryDelay, currentAttempt + 1, container);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: My gut instinct is stack overflow, given your function is recursive. So logging likely isn't working in that instance.

Comment: Why are you retrying?  You are running Async so you check if failed may be occurring before the data is actually saved.  The you are trying to save data that is already in the database and failing because you are writing duplicate data.  When you have a primary key you can only write one item with the same primary key.  So doing a retry is causing the issue because you are saving two items with the same key.

Comment: @jdweng The insert requests are being awaited
await Task.WhenAll(attemptAudits.Select(a => a.RunningTask));

Comment: The `var nonRetryableAudits = attemptAudits.Where(` code in the catch strikes me as odd. The name suggests it isn't retryable, but I see no evidence that you don't actually retry it. Plus, it reads the `a.RunningTask.Result.StatusCode` property when code just a few lines earlier checks whether `Result` is `null` (implying it _can_ be `null`) and yet that `null` check is not done here (which means you may be throwing an exception from within your catch perhaps?).

Comment: Use Bulk library instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-dot-net. It provides you result for all the records (error or success).